# AngularJS : display epoch in pst/pdt using date filter

Tags: angularjs

I am getting date in epoch format from the backend.

updatedOn = 1427171737000  (from backend)

I am using angular filter to display the date.

{{updatedOn | date: "MM/dd/yyyy ' ' h:mma Z" }}  ==> it turns to be 2015-03-23 21:35:37 -0700

I would like my output to be displayed in PST format which will be 2015-03-24 04:35:37

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 1.3+ of AngularJS then you just need to pass in the timezone

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/filter/date if you want to read further.

Comment: Could you please post an example of the using timezone?  I tried {{1427171737000 | date:'MM/dd/yyyy ' ' h:mma' : '+1400'}}  but didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

{{updatedOn | date: "MM/dd/yyyy" : 'PST' }}

Comment: I doubt that this code-only proposal helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help.